# Magento2 : Iterate over blocks and show them as products

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, custompage

I've got a set of blocks made in the backend. Now, I want the following to be possible:

- Iterate over a selected count of blocks, starting with a certain name (which would not be the hardest part) in a custom phtml file
- Show each block like as a product on my page
- When I click on a 'block product', a pop up will show up with content corresponding to that block.

Now, I already have the code for the pop up and stuff, but my question is:

Is it possible to iterate over a set of CMS blocks and show them on my page (and preferably in the same way a product, so more like a link to the block rather than the whole block content) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it as follows:

```
<ul class="block-list-grid">
<?php
// maximum of a hundred blocks
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    if (!empty($block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_' . $i)->toHtml())):?>
       // have corresponding image for each block and iterating over them
        <li class="block-list-image">
            <div class="block-list-grid-item" data-option="<?= $i ?>">
                <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('img_block_' . $i)->toHtml(); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php
    endif;
}
?>
    </ul>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
if (!empty($block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_' . $i)->toHtml())):?>
<div class="story-items">
    <div class="pop-up-mtm" data-option="<?= $i ?>">
        <div class="pop-up-text mtm-text-pop-up">
            <span class="close-popup-mtm"></span>
            <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_' . $i)->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
endif;
}
?>
```

So as you can see, I made blocks starting with 'img_block_', which contain images. The next loop that iterates over 'block_' is the content in the pop ups. When clicked on for instance the image of 'img_block_1', the popup with content of 'block_1' will show up.

A relative small piece of simple code.